# Sending transaction via nodejs backend , trying to send ether from one address to another

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, ethereumjs, dapp-debugging

I am trying to send ether from one account to another I am using the modules web3, express and ethereumjs-tx. And also Infura rinkey as my provider.

I am having problems that if the value is too high the transaction will fail, and when I try with a smaller number the transaction will work, but the ether sent wont be reflected on the other account.(I am using 2 metamask accounts), one for sending that has roughly 41 ethers. I tried playing around the value , gas limit, gas price. But did not work.

this is my js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Module that will interact to the ethereum.
const web3 = require('web3');
// Required for creating transactions.
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

const INFURA_BASE_URL = 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/';
const INFURA_API_KEY = 'infura api key';
web3js = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(INFURA_BASE_URL + INFURA_API_KEY));


/*
  Sender & Receiver keys
 */
const SENDER_PUBLIC_KEY = 'sender public key';
const SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY = Buffer.from('insert private key', 'hex');
const RECEIVER_PUBLIC_KEY = 'reciever public key';


const CONTRACT_ABI = [{} ];
const CONTRACT_ABI_ADDRESS = 'contract address';

/*
  A controller listening at: http://localhost:3000/send
 */
app.get('/send', function (req, res) {

  // creating contract object
  const contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ABI_ADDRESS, {from: SENDER_PUBLIC_KEY});

  

  // get transaction count, later will used as nonce
  web3js.eth.getTransactionCount(SENDER_PUBLIC_KEY)
    .then(function (numberOfTransactionsSent) {
      console.log("The number of transactions sent from the given address: " + numberOfTransactionsSent);

      // creating raw transaction
      const amount = web3js.utils.fromWei( await web3.eth.getBalance(SENDER_PUBLIC_KEY),
      
      'ether'

      );
      const rawTransaction = {
        from: SENDER_PUBLIC_KEY,
        gasPrice: web3js.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
        gasLimit: web3js.utils.toHex(310000),
        to: CONTRACT_ABI_ADDRESS,
        value: '0x00',
        data: contract.methods.transfer(RECEIVER_PUBLIC_KEY, amount).encodeABI(),
        nonce: web3js.utils.toHex(numberOfTransactionsSent)
      };
      console.log('rawTransaction: ', rawTransaction);

      // creating transaction via ethereumjs-tx
      const transaction = new EthereumTx(rawTransaction, {chain: 'rinkeby'});
      // signing transaction with private key
      transaction.sign(SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY);
      // sending transaction via web3js module
      const serializedTx = transaction.serialize();
      web3js.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
        .on('receipt', console.log)
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log('Error [sendSignedTransaction]', err);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Error [getTransactionCount]', err);
    })
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:3000`)
})
```

Heres my solidity smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


 contract owned  {
    
     address public owner;
      constructor ()
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
     modifier  onlyOwner
    {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function transferOwnership(address  newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
    
}


contract NLtoken is owned
    {
    
    uint public totalSupply;
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowence;
    event Transfer (address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint tokens);
    event Approval (address indexed _tokenOwner, address indexed _spender, uint tokens);
    
    constructor  (string tokenName, string tokenSymbol, uint initialSupply) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply*10**uint256(decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;
        name = tokenName;
        symbol = tokenSymbol;
    }
  
    
    
    
    function _transfer (address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) internal returns(bool success){
       require(_to != 0x0);
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transfer (address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    {
        require(_value <= allowence[_from][msg.sender]);
        allowence[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
        
    }
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)
    {
        allowence[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
        
    }
    function mintToken (address _target, uint256 _mintedAmount) onlyOwner  {
        balanceOf[_target] += _mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += _mintedAmount;
        emit Transfer(0, owner, _mintedAmount);
        emit Transfer (owner, _target,_mintedAmount);
    }
   function burn (uint256 _value)  onlyOwner returns (bool succes)
    {
        require (balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        totalSupply -= _value;
       /* emit burn(msg.sender, _value);*/
        return true;
        
    }

        
    }
```

My goal is to create a Dapp to send an ether from one address to another. I was trying to learn and see how to connection between the Dapp and ethereum work's by sending ether from one account to another. So I can later do it with my own token.

Any feedback is welcome whether is to help me with my question or any improvements I should make on my smart contract or js code.

Comment: You don't really need to write a smart contract if all you need is sending ether from one address to another. Secondly, your smart contract seems to be implementing a token similar to ERC20. And the code seems to be a mix of sending ETH and transferring tokens. Are you sure this is what you want to achieve?